# "Enclosing type" error in Processing/Java

Tags: java, class, processing

Is there anything wrong with the following Processing/Java code?

```
class SensorData{
  private float temperature;
  private float distance;

  SensorData(float temperature, float distance) {
    this.temperature  =  temperature;
    this.distance  =  distance;
  }

  float getTemperature() {
    return this.temperature;
  }

  float getDistance() {
    return this.distance;
  }
}
```

I keep getting the following message:

```
The nested type SensorData cannot hide an enclosing type
```

The context is a Processing project and the SensorData class is being used as objects of a sketch in the same project folder.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple things, because you're not writing C++, but C# or Java:

```
class SensorData{
  private:
    float temperature;
    float distance;

  public:
  SensorData(float temperature, float distance) {
    this->temperature  =  temperature;
    this->distance  =  distance;
  }

  float getTemperature() {
    return this->temperature;
  }

  float getDistance() {
    return this->distance;
  }
}
```

In C++ `this` is a pointer, so you need `->` to access elements.

Also, why are you using the same name for arguments and members? It works because you use `this->` before the member, but I suggest you change the parameter names.

Also, get used to using initializer lists. I'd write the class as:

```
class SensorData{
  private:
    float temperature;
    float distance;

  public:
  SensorData(float t, float d) : temperature(t), distance(d) {
  }

  float getTemperature() const {
    return temperature;
  }

  float getDistance() const {
    return distance;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic syntax errors:

```
class SensorData{
  private: // following lines are private access
   float temperature;
   float distance;

public: // following lines are public access
  SensorData(float temperature, float distance) {
    this->temperature  =  temperature; // this is a pointer
    this->distance  =  distance;
  }

  float getTemperature() {
    return this->temperature;
  }

  float getDistance() {
    return this->distance;
  }
};  // class declaration ends with semi-colon
```

Although you do not need to use `this` in this particular case. Also, your constructor could benefit from usin a constructor initialization list:

```
SensorData(float temperature, float distance) 
: temperature(temperature), distance(distance){
}
```

and your access methods should be `const`.

```
float getTemperature() const {
  return this->temperature;
}
```

In summary, get a good C++ book.

Comment: Maybe also `const` on those accessors? And don't forget about the initializer list.

Comment: I think a far more pressing issue would be to terminate the class declaration (statement) with a semicolon, lest you want to throw a beginner off to chase a compile error somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that it isn't C++.

In C++, *access-specifiers* (`public`, `protected`, and `private`) are not part of a *member-declaration*, but of *member-specification*. Thus they are separated from *member-declarations* by a colon (`:`), and apply to all following *member-declarations* until the next *access-specifier*.

The implicit `this` is of a pointer type, and thus to access it's fields, you use `operator->`.

A C++ class definition (or a *class-specifier*) statement is not terminated by a `}`, but by the following `;`. You can optionally define one or several variables of the class-type before the terminal `;`.

Comment: Yes, this is more of a comment than an answer, but it *is* a good guidance for someone who honestly didn't know what he/she is working on.

Comment: Pedantic - actually, that's a class *definition*. A class declaration (or forward-declaration, same thing), is just `class ClassName;` /pedantic